# can a sql 2005 ssis package be scheduled?

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

I have a data dump that I manually initiate and I want to automate things now that they are working well. I have a system that exports data into Excel that I ultimately want to import into a SQL table.

I have a ssis package that I used for the import and saved it for re-use later. I just manually ran it and it works well. Now I would like to have it run either when invoked by a file watcher or schedule or some thing so that all I need to do is over-write the excel file and have it trigger the ssis to run its import.

Any ideas on how to make this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server does its scheduling with SQL Agent, so try creating a schedule in that to do what you want.